# How to show unused foreign key value when joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, emp, and dept(employee and department).
Say I want to show the sum of all salaries per department, I could use something like:

```
select sum(sal), deptno
from emp
group by deptno
```

Now that works, but say there is a department in the list that has no employees, and I want it to show up also, how would I do that? I've tried joins, the nvl function, but no luck this far. For example, this works, but it won't show the empty departments:

```
select sum(emp.sal), dept.deptno
from emp, dept
where emp.deptno=dept.deptno
group by dept.deptno
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Adrian Since he mentions the NVL function, I'd guess Oracle.

Comment: Nice catch @JoeStefanelli, I over read that. Just updated the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` will do the trick:

```
select coalesce(sum(emp.sal),0), dept.deptno
from dept 
left join emp on emp.deptno=dept.deptno
group by dept.deptno
```

You should always explicitly declare your joins, so that you can change them when you need to. Implicit joins are always `INNER JOIN`.

Additionally, I change the query to show `0` instead of `NULL` when department has no employees, by using `COALESCE`.

Comment: Technically, the answer should be "an *outer* join will do the trick".  `LEFT JOIN` (shorthand for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) is one type of outer join.  The other two are `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  For details on outer joins in general [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins) provides a fairly good summary.

Comment: Good that you posted complementary info @Lee. I just simplified the answer for OP's convenience.

Comment: Thanks you both for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an outer join

```
SELECT 
   dept.deptno,
   SUM(emp.sal)
FROM
   dept 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN emp ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
GROUP BY
   dept.deptno
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a LEFT JOIN so that you return all departments, regardless of whether or not they have employees.

```
SELECT dept.deptno, SUM(emp.sal)
    FROM dept
        LEFT JOIN emp
            ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
    GROUP BY dept.deptno
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ISNULL(SUM(e.sal),0) AS SalSum,
        d.DeptNo
 FROM Dept AS d
 LEFT JOIN emp AS e ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo
 GROUP BY d.DeptNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join:

```
select 
  sum(emp.sal), dept.deptno
from dept LEFT OUTER JOIN emp
  ON dept.deptno=emp.deptno
group by dept.deptno
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative approach, justification being that it uses relational operators (union and difference) making it simple to read and understand, IMO:

```
select sum(sal), deptno
from emp
group by deptno

union

select 0, d.deptno
from dept d
minus
select 0, e.deptno
from emp e;
```

Comment: I didn't use an outer join -- call the SQL police! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(sal), deptno
from emp
group by deptno

union all

select 0, deptno
from dept
where deptno not in (select deptno from emp)
```

or

```
select sum(sal), deptno
from emp
group by deptno

union all

select 0, d.deptno
from dept d
where not exists
(
select * 
from emp e
where e.deptno = d.deptno
)
```

Comment: I'm adding mine since the answer is wrong, but I can't speak for anyone else.

Comment: you are showing how to get the results he wants but in the wrong method. Proper technique for this is to use an outer join, not to union the two queries.

Comment: JNK: this is hust another method. Do you want to repeat the `OUTER JOIN` solution?

Comment: No, this is why I didn't post an answer.  And it's not "just another method".  It's not extensible (imagine this with 4 tables instead of 2), it's going to be much slower since you are running multiple aggregated queries in sequence, and it's going to greatly complicate things like ordering since you will need to put the union as a subselect and then resort it AGAIN.  It's a bad answer.

Comment: Two tables are just two tables, not four or six. I agree it's not the fastest method. So all solutions without NVL/COALESCE function are ok ?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach, I'm learning sql so everything is welcome, but I'll keep in mind this one is less efficient for this kind of problem.

Comment: @JNK: "the wrong method"? "Proper technique for this is..."? I wasn't aware that this has been legislated on! Personally, I like this approach when there is only two tables involved and only knowledge of the actual data involved will dictate whether it is appropriate.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I'll stand by my downvote on this one.  It's inefficient and more challenging to scale.  It's still a "valid solution" but that doesn't make it a good one.